# Telegram Bots: secret chats possible?

Tags: chat, telegram-bot

Telegram offers "[secret chats](https://telegram.org/faq#secret-chats)". Is it possible that a bot opens a secret chat and sends a message? I could not find any method or parameter for this function.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Telegram's Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) **does not support** secret chats at the moment. You can read the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end), but a short explanation is: end-to-end encryption is used in secret chats which is tricky to implement for bots and requires additional work.

There's no word on when it'll be supported, if ever. At any rate, Telegram Bots are generally meant as a useful aid or for fun, not for sensitive things like financial transactions.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Do you know if the situation has changed in the meanwhile?

Comment: Financial transactions are now supported using a dedicated API. https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments

Comment: It will be great if there is any mean allows bot to send messages individually. Suppose that a company need to contact with one of their clients.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is too late, but following the post, I found out they support for [secret chat API REST API](https://core.telegram.org/methods#working-with-secret-chats) . You can check if still interested.

Comment: I got excited upon reading your answer, but unfortunately methods such as messages.sendEncrypted throw an error **"400: This method can't be used by a bot"**