# Is Telegram Bot communication secured via end-to-end encryption?

Tags: security, encryption, telegram, privacy, end-to-end

Despite controversy I like Telegram and it's bots. I would like using a couple of bots as personal assistants. However I'm paranoid with regards to secure network communication and data privacy. The idea of trusting my private data to some possibly mean kid or unsafe data storage is daunting.

So consequently I thought I snap twice, sing bibbidi-bobbidi-boo quickly and then have a self-written Telegram bot ready on a Raspberry Pi hosted in my basement (or possibly hosted in the cloud, when I trust the provider).

But then I'm wondering: **Is end-to-end encryption implemented for private chats with Telegram bots?** The Telegram clients are open source, however the server is not as far as I'm aware. And in general you never know what's happening behind the scenes on the servers of Telegram Messenger LLP.

I've ran up and the down the whole net twice, but I could only find the official, technical [documentation about end-to-end encryption](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end) in general. To me it seems private chats with bots are encrypted, but I just want to double-check I am not overseeing something. Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telegram Bots: secret chats possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093188/telegram-bots-secret-chats-possible)

Comment: @JamesKPolk: I was unsure, whether I should turn to Super User or here. Thank you for clarification, I will consider this the next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Telegram Bot API's are not end to end encrypted. based on [Telegram documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end) end to end encryption are for user's chat, without mentioning about bots:

> Secret Chats are one-on-one chats wherein messages are encrypted with a key held only by the chat’s participants.

You can implement it manually by adding encryption and decryption in both sides.

Same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093188/telegram-bots-secret-chats-possible).

Comment: You're right, thank you. I had the misconception, that Telegram had all of it's private chats encrypted, i.e. as not an option, but the default. Thanks for clarification and the link to the other question.

Comment: However, what do you mean though with implementing it manually?

Comment: How r u using the bot ?! how is app designed ?!

Comment: End-to-end encryption is only implemented in *Secret Chats*. No other messages are encrypted end-to-end.

Comment: @Majidkhalili: Not sure how to respond. I would like to use such bots with the phone or desktop client preferably in a private chat (i.e. no inline mode). I would prefer not to use webhooks for the bot, but that would also be ok, if that allows me a secure connection then.